# How can I wrap my light/dark mode theme around index.js while using my header as the switch location?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm a little confused on how to set up a theme wrapped around my index.js components, while using a switch state in my header.js that triggers `light` or `dark` theme.

trying to streamline this as much as possible to require less coding. However I'm a React Noob and would like some guidance on how I can set up my code properly to get everything working.

EDIT: Thanks to Diyorbek, I've managed to understand how to get this working. I'm now getting a `theme` is not defined for my `index.js` file

- `index.js`:

```
import { ThemeProvider, CssBaseline } from "@material-ui/core";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core";

const MyThemeContext = React.createContext({});

export function useMyThemeContext() {
  return useContext(MyThemeContext);
}

function MyThemeProvider(props) {
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const theme = useMemo(
    () =>
      createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
          type: isDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
        },
      }),
    [isDarkMode]
  );

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MyThemeContext.Provider value={{ isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode }}>
        {props.children}
      </MyThemeContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}


const routing = (
    <Router>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                    <Header />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
                    </Switch>
                    <Footer />
            </ThemeProvider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

`header.js`:

```
import { useMyThemeContext } from '../index';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    appBar: {
        borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    },
    link: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1, 1.5),
    },
    toolbarTitle: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
}));


function Header() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useMyThemeContext();

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar
                position="static"
                color="default"
                elevation={0}
                className={classes.appBar}
            >
                <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                    <Switch
                        checked={isDarkMode}
                        onChange={() => setIsDarkMode(!isDarkMode)}
                    />
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).
This is how I would approach this case:

```
const MyThemeContext = createContext({});

export function useMyThemeContext() {
  return useContext(MyThemeContext);
}

function MyThemeProvider(props) {
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const theme = useMemo(
    () =>
      createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
          type: isDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
        },
      }),
    [isDarkMode]
  );

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MyThemeContext.Provider value={{ isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode }}>
        {props.children}
      </MyThemeContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

const routing = (
  <Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <MyThemeProvider>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </MyThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>
);
```

```
import { useMyThemeContext } from "...."

function Header() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const {isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode} = useMyThemeContext();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="static"
        color="default"
        elevation={0}
        className={classes.appBar}
      >
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
          <Switch
            checked={isDarkMode}
            onChange={() => setIsDarkMode(!isDarkMode)}
          />
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about from exporting and importing the new functions to make them usable in my header?

Comment: I edited the code. We need to export `useMyThemeContext` hook. So then you can use it anywhere inside `MyThemeProvider`'s child components.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification @Diyorbek, I've managed to solve the errors previously. However now I'm getting an `useMemo` is not defined error, which I think is also causing a `theme` is not defined error. I've edited my original post, I don't think I copied something wrong. I would appreciate if you took a look.

Comment: Okay all I had to do was import `useMemo`, whoops! Still getting that undefined theme error however.

Comment: @Dre I didn't write import statements to keep the answer short. If you are using WebStorm or VSCode, they might be suggesting to import missing functions. You have to import them.

Comment: Looks like you didn't copy the `const routing` properly. You should use `<MyThemeProvider>` instead of  `<ThemeProvider>`.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for catching that. I am getting one last error, it says `
TypeError: Object is not a function` for the line: `const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useMyThemeContext();` in my `header.js`, I have exported function properly?

Comment: @Dre I updated the code. The variables should have been destructured from object not array.

Answer (score 1):

When working with react, if you want to change global variables that act like states, you'll want to use a Context. This allows you to access data and render components based on changes to this data throughout every page and component. Consult the [Context documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for more information & guides on usage.